# Views UI options do not work

Tags: views

I am building a drupal 7 site.

Lately I made a lot of changes and install many modules.

Currently, when I enter into a view, everything looks fine.
but, when I enter a field settings inside a view, I see that some of the option are not available - meaning the collapsible option is not available.

I tried to replace the views folder on my server with a folder I backed-up 4 days ago. 
ran cron, flushed all caches, ran upadte.php - nothing helped.

- Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Here is a screen-shot (you can see they are not clickable and not collapsible):
[image]

Comment: Disable jQuery update, then it'll start working again

Comment: To add to Clive, make sure it's not jQuery 1.8, 1.7 seems to work for me.

Comment: @Clive Do you mean jQuary update module? if so, I have the 7.x-2.3. I disabled this module, ran update.php, flushed the cache - still not working.

Comment: You could try to completely uninstall it on the 'uninstall'-tab. It is very common problem that module is causing the issue.

Comment: I have uninstall the jQuery Module, removed it from my "module folder", cleared the cache, ran cron, still not working..

Comment: Something else is breaking your javascript then - check the browser console, that'll tell you where the problem is

Comment: When I checked I saw a notice that is related to the advagg_js of the advagg module. I deactivated the advagg module, and it working now. Yesterday, I change some of the settings of the module according to this guide: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107311/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-above-the-fold-content

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The problem was an option on the [advagg module](https://drupal.org/project/advagg) that move all JS to the footer (which is usually a good thing).

The "All" option was problematic.
when I chose "Disabled" - the views UI worked correctly.

here is a screen-shot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From [Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107311/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-above-the-fold-content/107332)
Sometimes moving all JS to the footer can cause unintended side effects. Under advagg/mod under "Move JS to the footer" try "All but JavaScript Libraries". This will decrease your pagespeed score but a working site is better.

Comment: When I am not developing the site, and not trying to access the views UI, can I choose "All" (and not "All but JavaScript Libraries")?

Comment: Can you create a feature request on this https://drupal.org/project/issues/advagg?version=7.x linking to this page?

Comment: Which feature request? please explain and I will open it. When I am not developing the site, and not trying to access the views UI, can I choose "All"?

Comment: I created the issue https://drupal.org/node/2223417