# How to improve the speed of drupal website

Tags: performance

I have tested my site with testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com. I got the below report. Speed test score for mobile site and desktop site are not good.  If you could help me pointing to right direction to fix this errors and bring the score higher, it would help me a lot. Resources they provided are in general. I am looking more drupal specific resources.

**MOBILE FRIENDLINESS**
98/100
GOOD
**MOBILE SPEED**
57/100
POOR
**DESKTOP SPEED**
52/100
POOR
[image]
[image]

Update New result:

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: I mean, the pointers are in the report... this is kind of too broad otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend you a very popular module: https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg . This is better than the standard aggregation in Drupal, you need to configure it a bit after you install it.

For the images, you can you something like this: https://www.drupal.org/project/imageapi_optimize . This will optimize your images and should help you pass that.

Comment: I will follow your advise and test. I will let you know the result.

Comment: I used the two modules you recommended. I got better score. How can I have higher score than that?

Comment: @Drupol see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107311/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-above-the-fold-content/107332#107332