# Getting CSS content above the fold and I'm not quite sure why

Tags: 7, theming

I am getting this error for Page Speed insights, but I have followed the instructions I saw here to a T, and also tried messing around with it a bit.

[Here's the link to the instructions.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107311/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-above-the-fold-content/107332)

I'm still getting CSS content above the fold - with 10 files on the mobile version and 17 on the desktop. What would be causing this? I'm now using 7.x-2.26 as opposed to 7.x-2.19. Trying to load the CSS in the footer doesn't help me out, nor anything else I'm doing.

What's a way to ensure that CSS is only loaded in such a way that page speed insights doesn't hate the site?

Instructions can be module-driven or technical, as I can write any custom code.

Comment: Do you mean "as opposed to 7-2.9"?

Comment: Actually meant 7.x-2.26, fixed it

Comment: Okay, in the linked tutorial, it mentions using version 7.x-2.19. Have you tried using that version?

Comment: I'd prefer to not use a version that's seven updates out of date unless I have a good reason to, and I don't see any specific reason why the instructions wouldn't work in 2.26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that if you have `base_path().path_to_theme()` as the location of your CSS, which the theme I was modifying did, it will not aggregate cleanly with either Drupal's standard aggregation nor with AdvAgg's aggregation.