# How to prevent my ZURB theme from stripping out part of the JSON LD element?

Tags: theming

I use [ZURB theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/zurb_foundation) and following I post the code of my template.php file.

My problem is, that `type="application/ld+json"` in `<script type="application/ld+json">` gets stripped out so it is rendered as just `<script>`.

The problem with this is that I can't add structured markup to any pages.

To reproduce just insert jsonld script in any way (third party module or using custom fields for nodes) and display it with a zurb theme.

The same issue has already been reported for ZEN: https://www.drupal.org/project/zen/issues/2934644

To I have to adapt my template.php in a similar way as suggested in the ZEN patch in terms of not stripping out JSON-ld?

Here is my template.php

```
    <?php

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 *
 */
//function gonzo_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
//  // Add conditional CSS for IE. To use uncomment below and add IE css file
//  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/ie.css', array('weight' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('!IE' => FALSE), 'preprocess' => FALSE));
//
//  // Need legacy support for IE downgrade to Foundation 2 or use JS file below
//  // drupal_add_js('http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE7.js', 'external');
//}

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_page
 *
 */
//function gonzo_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
//}

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_node
 *
 */
//function gonzo_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
//}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_block()
 */
//function gonzo_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
//  // Add wrapping div with global class to all block content sections.
//  $variables['content_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'block-content';
//
//  // Convenience variable for classes based on block ID
//  $block_id = $variables['block']->module . '-' . $variables['block']->delta;
//
//  // Add classes based on a specific block
//  switch ($block_id) {
//    // System Navigation block
//    case 'system-navigation':
//      // Custom class for entire block
//      $variables['classes_array'][] = 'system-nav';
//      // Custom class for block title
//      $variables['title_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'system-nav-title';
//      // Wrapping div with custom class for block content
//      $variables['content_attributes_array']['class'] = 'system-nav-content';
//      break;
//
//    // User Login block
//    case 'user-login':
//      // Hide title
//      $variables['title_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'element-invisible';
//      break;
//
//    // Example of adding Foundation classes
//    case 'block-foo': // Target the block ID
//      // Set grid column or mobile classes or anything else you want.
//      $variables['classes_array'][] = 'six columns';
//      break;
//  }
//
//  // Add template suggestions for blocks from specific modules.
//  switch($variables['elements']['#block']->module) {
//    case 'menu':
//      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__nav';
//    break;
//  }
//}

//function gonzo_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
//}

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_panels_pane().
 *
 */
//function gonzo_preprocess_panels_pane(&$variables) {
//}

/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_views_fields().
 *
 */
//function gonzo_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables) {
//}

/**
 * Implements theme_form_element_label()
 * Use foundation tooltips
 */
//function gonzo_form_element_label($variables) {
//  if (!empty($variables['element']['#title'])) {
//    $variables['element']['#title'] = '<span class="secondary label">' . $variables['element']['#title'] . '</span>';
//  }
//  if (!empty($variables['element']['#description'])) {
//    $variables['element']['#description'] = ' <span data-tooltip="top" class="has-tip tip-top" data-width="250" title="' . $variables['element']['#description'] . '">' . t('More information?') . '</span>';
//  }
//  return theme_form_element_label($variables);
//}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_button().
 */
//function gonzo_preprocess_button(&$variables) {
//  $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'button';
//  if (isset($variables['element']['#parents'][0]) && $variables['element']['#parents'][0] == 'submit') {
//    $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'secondary';
//  }
//}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 * Example of using foundation sexy buttons
 */
//function gonzo_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
//  // Sexy submit buttons
//  if (!empty($form['actions']) && !empty($form['actions']['submit'])) {
//    $classes = (is_array($form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class']))
//      ? $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class']
//      : array();
//    $classes = array_merge($classes, array('secondary', 'button', 'radius'));
//    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'] = $classes;
//  }
//}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 * Example of using foundation sexy buttons on comment form
 */
//function gonzo_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Sexy preview buttons
//  $classes = (is_array($form['actions']['preview']['#attributes']['class']))
//    ? $form['actions']['preview']['#attributes']['class']
//    : array();
//  $classes = array_merge($classes, array('secondary', 'button', 'radius'));
//  $form['actions']['preview']['#attributes']['class'] = $classes;
//}


/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_panels_pane().
 */
// function zurb_foundation_preprocess_panels_pane(&$variables) {
// }

/**
* Implements template_preprocess_views_views_fields().
*/
/* Delete me to enable
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables) {
 if ($variables['view']->name == 'nodequeue_1') {

   // Check if we have both an image and a summary
   if (isset($variables['fields']['field_image'])) {

     // If a combined field has been created, unset it and just show image
     if (isset($variables['fields']['nothing'])) {
       unset($variables['fields']['nothing']);
     }

   } elseif (isset($variables['fields']['title'])) {
     unset ($variables['fields']['title']);
   }

   // Always unset the separate summary if set
   if (isset($variables['fields']['field_summary'])) {
     unset($variables['fields']['field_summary']);
   }
 }
}

// */

/**
 * Implements hook_css_alter().
 */
//function gonzo_css_alter(&$css) {
//  // Always remove base theme CSS.
//  $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'zurb_foundation');
//
//  foreach($css as $path => $values) {
//    if(strpos($path, $theme_path) === 0) {
//      unset($css[$path]);
//    }
//  }
//}

/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 */
//function gonzo_js_alter(&$js) {
//  // Always remove base theme JS.
//  $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'zurb_foundation');
//
//  foreach($js as $path => $values) {
//    if(strpos($path, $theme_path) === 0) {
//      unset($js[$path]);
//    }
//  }
//}

// Enabling customized login form (attempt I)
// function gonzo_theme() {
//   $items = array();
// 
//   $items['user_login'] = array(
//     'render element' => 'form',
//     'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'gonzo') . '/templates',
//     'template' => 'user-login',
//     'preprocess functions' => array(
//        'gonzo_preprocess_user_login'
//     ),
//   );
//    $items['user_register_form'] = array(
//      'render element' => 'form',
//      'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'gonzo') . '/templates',
//      'template' => 'user-register-form',
//      'preprocess functions' => array(
//        'gonzo_preprocess_user_register_form'
//      ),
//    );
//    $items['user_pass'] = array(
//      'render element' => 'form',
//      'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'gonzo') . '/templates',
//      'template' => 'user-pass',
//      'preprocess functions' => array(
//        'gonzo_preprocess_user_pass'
//      ),
//    );
//   return $items;
// }

// function gonzo_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
//   $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome login form');
// }

//  function gonzo_preprocess_user_register_form(&$vars) {
//    $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my super awesome reg form');
//  }
//  
//  function gonzo_preprocess_user_pass(&$vars) {
//    $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my super awesome request new password form');
//  }

// Enabling customized login form attempt II
function gonzo_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  //print_r($form) // This will display form elements.
  if($form_id == "user_login_block") {
      $form['actions']['submit']['#value']= "›";
  }
}

// Enabling customized Teaser Display
function gonzo_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if($vars['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $vars['node']->type . '__teaser';   
  }
}

// Customizing visibilty radio buttons in edit/create form
// function theme_form_element (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_radios/7)
function gonzo_form_element($variables) {
  $element = &$variables ['element'];

  // This function is invoked as theme wrapper, but the rendered form element
  // may not necessarily have been processed by form_builder().
  $element += array(
    '#title_display' => 'before',
  );

  // Add element #id for #type 'item'.
  if (isset($element ['#markup']) && !empty($element ['#id'])) {
    $attributes ['id'] = $element ['#id'];
  }
  // Add element's #type and #name as class to aid with JS/CSS selectors.
  $attributes ['class'] = array('form-item');
  if (!empty($element ['#type'])) {
    $attributes ['class'][] = 'form-type-' . strtr($element ['#type'], '_', '-');
  }
  if (!empty($element ['#name'])) {
    $attributes ['class'][] = 'form-item-' . strtr($element ['#name'], array(' ' => '-', '_' => '-', '[' => '-', ']' => ''));
  }
  // Add a class for disabled elements to facilitate cross-browser styling.
  if (!empty($element ['#attributes']['disabled'])) {
    $attributes ['class'][] = 'form-disabled';
  }

  // only prints the wrapper for elements that are not radio elements
  $output = '';
  if ($element['#type'] != 'radios' && $element['#type'] != 'radio') {
    $output = '<div' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . "\n";
  }

  // If #title is not set, we don't display any label or required marker.
  if (!isset($element ['#title'])) {
    $element ['#title_display'] = 'none';
  }
  $prefix = isset($element ['#field_prefix']) ? '<span class="field-prefix">' . $element ['#field_prefix'] . '</span> ' : '';
  $suffix = isset($element ['#field_suffix']) ? ' <span class="field-suffix">' . $element ['#field_suffix'] . '</span>' : '';

  switch ($element ['#title_display']) {
    case 'before':
    case 'invisible':
      $output .= ' ' . theme('form_element_label', $variables);
      $output .= ' ' . $prefix . $element ['#children'] . $suffix . "\n";
      break;

    case 'after':
      $output .= ' ' . $prefix . $element ['#children'] . $suffix;
      $output .= ' ' . theme('form_element_label', $variables) . "\n";
      break;

    if (strpos($element['#id'], 'edit-group-content-access-und') !== FALSE) {
      $output .= "<span class=\"switch-selection\"></span>\n";
    }


    case 'none':
    case 'attribute':
      // Output no label and no required marker, only the children.
      $output .= ' ' . $prefix . $element ['#children'] . $suffix . "\n";
      break;
  }

  if (!empty($element ['#description'])) {
    $output .= '<div class="description">' . $element ['#description'] . "</div>\n";
  }

  //only prints the wrapper for elements that are not radio elements
  if ($element['#type'] != 'radios' && $element['#type'] != 'radio') {
    $output .= "</div>\n";
  }  

//  if (strpos($element['#id'], 'edit-og-group-ref') !== FALSE) {
  return $output;
//  }

//  dpm(strpos($element['#id'], 'edit-og-group-ref'));
//  if (strpos($element['#id'], 'edit-og-group-ref') !== FALSE) {
//  dpm(strpos($element));
//  return $output;
//  }

}


// function theme_radios (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_radio/7)
function gonzo_radios($variables) {
  $element = $variables ['element'];
  $attributes = array();
  if (isset($element ['#id'])) {
    $attributes ['id'] = $element ['#id'];
  }
  $attributes ['class'] = 'form-radios';
  if (!empty($element ['#attributes']['class'])) {
    $attributes ['class'] .= ' ' . implode(' ', $element ['#attributes']['class']);
  }
  if (isset($element ['#attributes']['title'])) {
    $attributes ['title'] = $element ['#attributes']['title'];
  }
  return '<div' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . (!empty($element ['#children']) ? $element ['#children'] : '') . '<span class="switch-selection"></span></div>';

}

/**
 * Custom changes by Gonzo 13. 1. 2018 from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107311/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-above-the-fold-content#107332
 * Implements hook_page_alter().
 */
function gonzo_page_alter(&$page) {
  // Get critical css file.
  $filename = FALSE;
  $current_path = current_path();
  $path = drupal_get_path('theme', $GLOBALS['theme']);
  // Detect frontpage.
  if (!$filename
    && drupal_is_front_page()
    && is_readable("$path/critical-css/urls/front.css")
  ) {
    $filename = "$path/critical-css/urls/front";
  }
  // Detect specific urls.
  if (!$filename
    && is_readable("$path/critical-css/urls/{$current_path}.css")
  ) {
    $filename = "$path/critical-css/urls/{$current_path}";
  }
  // Detection by node type.
  if (!$filename) {
    $object = menu_get_object();
    if (isset($object->nid)
      && is_readable("$path/critical-css/node_type/{$object->type}.css")
    ) {
      $filename = "$path/critical-css/node_type/{$object->type}";
    }
  }

  // Add inline critical css for front page.
  if (!empty($filename)) {
    $inline_css = advagg_load_stylesheet("$filename.css", TRUE);
    $page['content']['#attached']['css']["$filename.css"] = array(
      'data' => $inline_css,
      'type' => 'inline',
      'group' => CSS_SYSTEM - 1,
      'weight' => -50000,
      'movable' => FALSE,
      'critical-css' => TRUE,
    );
    // Add in domain prefetch.
    if (is_readable("$filename.dns")) {
      $domains = file("$filename.dns", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
      $domains = array_unique($domains);
      foreach ($domains as $domain) {
        advagg_add_dns_prefetch($domain);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR – Simply deactivate this behavior in Zurb's theme settings. See screenshot below.

---

The [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen/issues/2934644) you mentioned already has a working [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/zen-n2934644-3.patch) attached that actually seems to fix the issue in Zen by adding a simple condition to the function in the base-theme that causes this unwanted behavior.

**Before the Zen patch**

```
if (isset($tag['#attributes']['type']) && $tag['#attributes']['type'] !== 'text/ng-template') {
  unset($tag['#attributes']['type']);
}
```

**After the Zen patch**

```
if (isset($tag['#attributes']['type'])) {
  if ($tag['#attributes']['type'] !== 'text/ng-template' && $tag['#attributes']['type'] !== 'application/ld+json') {
    unset($tag['#attributes']['type']);
  }
}
```

---

So all you have to do now is to go over to Zurb, create an issue, create a patch, add that patch to the issue, then patch your theme with that patch, done :)

Just look out for the `zurb_foundation_process_html_tag` function  in Zurb's `template.php` and then write the same condition as above around the following responsible line:

**Before you created the Zurb patch**

```
// Remove type="..."
unset($el['#attributes']['type']);
```

**After you created the Zurb patch**

```
// Remove type="..."
if (isset($el['#attributes']['type'])) {
  if ($el['#attributes']['type'] !== 'text/ng-template' && $el['#attributes']['type'] !== 'application/ld+json') {
    unset($el['#attributes']['type']);
  }
}
```

---

Creating a patch for the first time might seem a little bit scary, but actually it's pretty simple. Just git clone the repo, checkout the branch you wanna apply this patch for, then change the code, then type `git diff` and define a filename where `XXXXX` is the number of the issue and `YY` is the comment number.

```
git diff > issue_title_or_short_description-XXXXX-YY.patch
```

See [Making a Drupal patch with Git](https://www.drupal.org/node/707484) for more detailed info.

---

### Theme settings

Dayum, only after I wrote this whole long answer I became aware of this line in the code:

```
function zurb_foundation_process_html_tag(&$vars) {
  if (theme_get_setting('zurb_foundation_html_tags')) {
```

Means there are theme settings and you can simply **disable** "Prune HTML Tags":

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much @leymanx! You put so much effort into this and it helped me understand the concept of the template file. However, as you noted, I could achieve what I wanted by using the theme settings. Thank you very much for your help nontheless it is much appreciated!